# Getting error in Make "My App" public (Android)

Tags: android, makefile, public

I have searched a lot on this issue, but no one got this issue, what i am facing. The issue is, that when i try to make my App live or Public in Facebook for developers, it gives the following error.
[Click to open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOPcp.png)

I have already updated the contact email, I want this issue resolved without putting anything on play store etc.

Comment: you cannot make it public without releasing it on playstore. why dont you use test device, it will work

Comment: in test device who can login to app using Facebook authentication?

Comment: only devices that you mark as test through your code